# Transparency in models?

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, blender

This is a followup of this question: [Odd geometry with 3D models XNA + Blender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500629/odd-geometry-with-3d-models-xna-blender)

I successfully solved the problem with help, but I'm having a new problem. The models are transparent even though they aren't in Blender.

[image: 1]

I now know that it's probably something to do with blender, not XNA, but I'm still stumped, and I can't find a solid answer anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is meant to look transparent. What I see is the handle is drawn in front of the barrel, to me that implies an incorrect drawing order - you should draw the handle then the barrel over the top of it.

I'm not familiar with xna but in your previous question you appear to just draw each object as in the order they are given to you, one thing I would check is the object origins, they may impact the drawing order. In blender select the objects and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> (Also available from the Object->Transform menu) and choose Origin to Geometry. Otherwise look into determining the sorting order of objects.

[image]

If you do have some faces that are transparent then one possibility is the normals are facing the wrong way, only one side of a face is usually drawn. When in edit mode select all and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> with re-calculate the normals, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> will calculate the opposite way.

Also blender has it's own [stackexchange site now](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) you should find more blender specific help there.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a transparency problem... it a draw order problem...

If you enable Depth buffer it will be drawn well.

Before drawing the models add this:

```
    GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
```